# Need advise in image processing and binarization

Tags: image, image-processing

On this picure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfPqv.png

I have to reduse texture noise and sharpen the borders of the both squares to make possible applying binarization in order to recognize those squares. I tried to use median filters, sharpen filters with different matrixes but had no success. Can you, please, advise me something useful and working in the situation. Maybe, you know some binarization methods which will help me even without filters. Thanks.

Comment: just use canny edge http://i.stack.imgur.com/sBJzz.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Well, in that picture, the noise can be described as saturation and/or luminosity, and the information can be described as hue. So you probably want to convert RGB to HSB. See: [convert hsl to hsb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819844/convert-hsl-to-hsb)

If you do that, then equalize your saturation and brightness/lightness, you should take the noise out of the image.