# Zebra striping a html table with a twist

Tags: javascript, css, zebra-striping

Let's say I had Two tables, one has white rows, and one has all green rows.

I currently have stripeTable code that does this for white backgrounds:

```
function stripeTables($tables) {
    $("tbody tr:odd td,tbody tr:odd th", $tables).css("background-color", "#f7f6f6");
}
```

but I'd want a function that kind of makes the odd rows a bit darker, so that if the base background isn't white, it still just varies 'some RGB' value *'darker'* so that I do not have to select a different colour.

Any Ideas on how to do this in a fast way? I was thinking of reading RGB values of the background and then calculating a darker value for it, but i'm quite clueless on how to do that.

**UPDATE:**

The problem I have with the  **jquery-color** solution is that I need to provide the current bg color,
since that can be set on td/th level AND tr level AND TABLE level AND any other element above I can't really be sure that my table will have color X as background.  At least not when using $(this).css('background-color'), (this returns undefined if the background-color is not defined at CSS level of thing i'm applying the stripe color to.

using jsColors getRGB function in the way presented over at [jQuery and colour calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241618/jquery-and-colour-calculation)

```
function stripeTables($tables) {
    //    $("tbody tr:odd td,tbody tr:odd th", $tables).css("background-color", "#f7f6f6");
    $("tbody",$tables).each(function () {
        $("tr:odd td,tr:odd th", $(this)).css('background-color', function () {

            var rgb = getRGB($(this).css('background-color'));
            if (!rgb) {
                rgb = getRGB("#FFF");
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < rgb.length; i++) {
                rgb[i] = Math.max(0, rgb[i] - 10);
            }
            var newColor = 'rgb(' + rgb[0] + ',' + rgb[1] + ',' + rgb[2] + ')';
            return newColor;

        }, 1500);
    });
}
```

*code only works with white backgrounds now:*

**Concrete Updated question, I need to get to know the ACTUAL background color hex/rgb of an element, even if it's not set at that CSS LEVEL**

Comment: Why not just give the rows a black background and then vary the opacity?

Comment: You would need to know the bg-color of the normal table rows anyway. But if you do you might want to try this plugin: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/

Comment: Pointy, Don't you think the opacity variations will create transparant row data?

@tborychowski that looks nice, gonna test around with it a bit

Comment: I believe Pointy is right.  Otherwise you may have to look ingo hexadecimal math to figure out what a lighter color may be.  Wouldn't worth the time IMO

Comment: If you use a pre-processor like SASS you could do this by assigning classes for even/odd and using the `darken()` method.