# Changing a color brightness

Tags: javascript, colors, rgb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Increase CSS brightness color on click with jquery/javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833624/increase-css-brightness-color-on-click-with-jquery-javascript)

In JavaScript, how I can change a color's brightness, when we know the values of red, blue ,green much like it can be done in MSPaint?

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan - Opacity? I think you're mistaken...

Comment: You probably want to see [Pointy's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2348659/451969) and manipulate the lightness or value ("brightness") in `hsl`/`hsv`, he provides RGB to HSV or HSL functions.

Comment: Here is a method by [Converting RGB value to HSV to change the brigthness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833624/increase-css-brightness-color-on-click-with-jquery-javascript)

Comment: i found this http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/brightness/

Comment: The question linked as "exact duplicate" is very badly answered.

Answer (score 2):

The question is unrelated to Javascript, and I don't know what is the effect you are relating to MSPaint. Plus, converting between color spaces just to adjust brightness might be too expensive. There is a much simpler approach that might be good enough for you, which is a gamma correction that is fast and simple to perform. If your values of red, green, and blue are in the range [0, 255] you can also easily create a lookup-table (`lut`) which will be used to quickly apply the gamma correction for a given value in the range [0, 255]. The pseudocode for this method is:

```
GAMMA = k

lut = []
for i = 0 to 255
    v = i/255.0
    lut.push(round(255 * (v ^ GAMMA)))

foreach x, y in image
    image[x, y] = lut[image[x, y]]
```

A value of `k` greater than 1 will brighten the image, and lower than 1 will darken the image. The gamma correction is applied to each pixel component (i.e., red, green, and blue individually). Here are some examples with `k = 1, 2, 3`, respectively:

[image] [image] [image]

The full Python code to perform this (might help in the Javascript translation):

```
import sys
from PIL import Image

GAMMA = 1/3.0

lut = []
for i in xrange(256):
    v = i/255.
    lut.append(round(255 * (v ** GAMMA)))

img = Image.open(sys.argv[1])
img = img.point(lambda x: lut[x])
img.save(sys.argv[2])
```