# Changing pixel in canvas imageData to hsl(60, 100%, 50%)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I would like to change pixels of an `HTML5 canvas` to an `hsl` value. It could be any `hsl` value that is chosen by the user.

I can get the canvas imageData with `var imageData = canvas.getImageData(0, 0, 200, 200);`

But the `imageData.data` array contains values in `rgba`. Actually each value in the array is a byte so -

`data[0] = r, data[1] = b, data[2] = g, data[3] = a, data[4] = r, data[5] = b, data[6] = g, data[7] = a` etc.

Is there an `api` that can be used to manipulate imageData? An `api` that would abstract the raw data so that - `data[0] = rgba, data[1] = rgba` etc?

And that might have methods like - `data[0].setValueHSL(60, 100%, 50%);`

If this api does not exist is there a class that can create/represent an hsl value and which can convert the value to rgb?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if you are still looking for the answer since this was asked a long time ago. But I was trying to do the same and encountered the answer on [Why doesn't this Javascript RGB to HSL code work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348597/why-doesnt-this-javascript-rgb-to-hsl-code-work), this should do the trick :

```
function rgbToHsl(r, g, b) {
    r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;

    var max = Math.max(r, g, b);
    var min = Math.min(r, g, b);
    var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

    if (max == min) {
        h = s = 0; // achromatic
    } else {
        var d = max - min;
        s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
        switch(max) {
            case r: h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0); break;
            case g: h = (b - r) / d + 2; break;
            case b: h = (r - g) / d + 4; break;
        }
        h /= 6;
    }

    return 'hsl(' + Math.floor(h * 360) + ',' + Math.floor(s * 100) + '%,' + Math.floor(l * 100) + '%)';

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write one its as simple as this

```
parseImageData = function(imageData) {
    var newImageData = [];
    for ( var i = imageData - 1; i>0; i-4) {
        newImageData.push([ imageData[i],
                            imageData[i-1],
                            imageData[i-2],
                            imageData[i-3] ]);
    }
    return newImageData;
}
```

then if you want to convert it back

```
parseNewImageData = function ( newImageData ) {
    var imageData = [];
    for ( var i = newImageData - 1; i>=0; --i) {
        imageData.push( imageData[i][0] );
        imageData.push( imageData[i][1] );
        imageData.push( imageData[i][2] );
        imageData.push( imageData[i][3] );
    }
    return imageData;
}
```

super easy and you can make it do specifically what you need it to!

I hope this helps!