# Filter Hex Colors

Tags: javascript, html, css, hex

I have a huge list of diffferent hex colors (>6500) and I want to remove colors which are very dark and colors which are very bright.

How can I do this?
Is there a specific charachteristic in the bright and dark hex color codes which I can use to filter them out? Do I need to convert them to integers..?

Thank you!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596216/formula-to-determine-brightness-of-rgb-color

Comment: If all 3 groups of 2 are low numbers, the colour will be dark

Comment: You could [convert RGB to HSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348597/why-doesnt-this-javascript-rgb-to-hsl-code-work)

Comment: Hexadecimal color codes _are_ integers already...

Comment: I assume you want to either _Filter_ or to _Hitler_ (whatever the eff that would mean) the colors … so please correct the title ;-)

Comment: @ppeterka not greatly logical integers, however. `#0000FF` is only marginally different from `#1000FF`, but 255 is vastly different from 1048831. You'd be better off converting them to rgb first.

Comment: @James: so are they integers, or not?

Comment: @ppeterka yes but you wouldn't simply read them as integers as it wouldn't be logical. `#000000` is 3 separate `00` bytes, *not* one three-byte integer.

Comment: @ppeterka 3 unsigned bytes would be more exact i think :)

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Oh, I bow in front of you, I surely didn't know that. No-no. Not at all. Did you expect that? I didn't expect someone not understanding the meaning of the word _joke_ either... Especially in context of a meaningful question supported by facts, and reflecting deep research like this one...

Comment: @ppeterka I don't see why you're taking this so badly. Making a joke is all well and good but not when you're doing it in a way that could confuse the author of the question. I simply pointed out that hexadecimal colour codes *aren't* logical integers and that you *wouldn't* use them as logical integers.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick and dirty method that might do:

Separate your Hex colour into the R/G/B bytes.

Convert the hex bytes to decimal, add them together and divide by 3 to get a rough idea of average "brightness".

Choose an upper limit and a lower limit of how bright you would like your colours to be within the maximum possible range of 0 to 255, and exclude any that are outside of those two limits.

E.G.

#FFBBAA => FF BB AA => ( 255 + 187 + 170 ) / 3 = 204.

If you decide 200 is your upper limit on "brightness", this colour is too bright. The limits you set are entirely subjective, so up to you.

If you are comfortable with doing calculations in Hex directly, you can skip the conversion to decimal altogether and keep all the calculations in Hex.

Answer (score 1):

This function uses a regexp to parse the string value and returns the brightness from 0 (black) to 1 (100% white).

```
function hexBrightness(hex) {
    var regExp = hex.length < 6 ? /^#(([a-f\d]))(([a-f\d]))(([a-f\d]))$/i : /^#([a-f\d])([a-f\d])([a-f\d])([a-f\d])([a-f\d])([a-f\d])$/i;

    var result = regExp.exec(hex);
    if (result) {
        var r = parseInt("" + result[1] + result[2], 16),
            g = parseInt("" + result[3] + result[4], 16),
            b = parseInt("" + result[5] + result[6], 16),
            max = Math.max(r, g, b),
            min = Math.min(r, g, b),
            l = (max + min) / 2;
        return l / 255;
    }
    return null;
}

// Test
var assert = function (assertion, name) {
    $("<p/>").appendTo(document.body).text(name + (assertion ? ' works' : ' fails'))
}
assert(hexBrightness('#FFFFFF') == 1, 'Uppercase');
assert(hexBrightness('#ffffff') == 1, 'Lowercase');
assert(hexBrightness('#fff') == 1, 'Short');
assert(hexBrightness('#000') == 0, 'Black');
assert(hexBrightness('invalid') == null, 'Invalid color');
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L7PqT/