# How to calculate required hue-rotate to generate specific colour?

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-filters, css-filters

I have a white image that I am using as a background for a div, and I would like to colour to match the themes main colour. I am aware I can do:

```
filter: sepia() saturate(10000%) hue-rotate(30deg);
```

and cycle through `hue-rotate` to find a colour, but is it possible to calculate this value in advance? Given that the specified hex value is quite dark, I imagine I will need to include the `invert(%)` filter as well.

Given a hex value of `#689d94` what math do I need to do to calculate the desired `hue-rotate` and `invert` value to convert my white background image into the same colour?

### Edit

Here's a snippet of a `div` with a white background image being filtered green. The trick here, is it is the whole of the `div` that is being filtered, not just the image. If I was to enter some text into the `div` the text colour would turn green as well.

```css
div {
  background:url(http://richard.parnaby-king.co.uk/basket.svg) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  background-size:5em;
  width:5em;
  height:5em;
  -webkit-filter: invert(25%) sepia() saturate(100000%) hue-rotate(174deg);
  filter: invert(25%) sepia() saturate(100000%) hue-rotate(174deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<p style="background: #689d94">​</p>
```

Comment: Is it possible to use an in-line svg filter?

Comment: Re: *“Is it possible to use an in-line svg filter?”* — **YES, absolutely** — see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037023/#72369382) below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

##### The only way to get the exact match is to use an SVG color matrix filter.

For RGB color `#689d94`, which is `rgb(104, 157, 148)`, divide each primary color's value by 255:

[image]

Put these weights into the SVG `<filter>` matrix *(5ᵗʰ column in the first 3 rows)*:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <filter id="689d94" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" 
        values="0 0 0 0 0.40784 
                0 0 0 0 0.61569 
                0 0 0 0 0.58039 
                0 0 0 1 0"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

The `<filter>` has to have **id** (I used the RGB hex code `689d94`), so we can use it as a reference.

Since some browsers (e.g. Firefox) don't see/use the SVG filter if the `display` property of the SVG element is set to `none`, and having this SVG element in HTML code would inconveniently occupy some space, the best way is to convert this SVG into a pure inline CSS filter.

To get an **inline filter** value, take the above listed SVG code, transform it into a single line by remove line breaks and unnecessary spaces, then prepend `url('data:image/svg+xml,` and append the previously mentioned **id** as `#689d94')`:

```css
div {
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="71.063" height="60.938"><path d="M33.938 0l-16.97 19.906H1.625L0 21.781v8.781l1.25 1.407h4.781l5.875 28.969h46.969l6.188-28.97h4.687l1.313-1.343v-8.844L69.5 19.906H54.656L37.312 0h-3.375zm1.593 7.594l9.594 12.312H26.25l9.281-12.312zm-20.281 16s-.405 2.9 1.594 3.844c1.998.942 4.406.03 4.406.03-1.666 2.763-3.638 3.551-5.469 2.688-3.312-1.562-.531-6.562-.531-6.562zm41.188.031s2.749 4.969-.563 6.531c-2.487 1.162-4.848-1.541-5.438-2.656 0 0 2.377.88 4.375-.063 1.999-.942 1.625-3.812 1.625-3.812z"/></svg>') no-repeat; // optimized from http://richard.parnaby-king.co.uk/basket.svg
  background-size: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 5em;
  width: 5em;
}
#colored {
  filter: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><defs><filter id="689d94" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"><feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.40784 0 0 0 0 0.61569 0 0 0 0 0.58039 0 0 0 1 0"/></filter></defs></svg>#689d94');
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- No <svg> in HTML; pure CSS -->
<div></div><div id="colored"></div>
<p style="background: #689d94">​</p>
```

Comment: "the best way is to convert this SVG into a pure inline CSS filter." Note that this doesn't work on Safari; known webkit bug. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67634831/css-filter-property-does-not-work-on-safari-when-using-inline-svg-in-css-like , https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=104169

Answer (score 103):

The key in this case is to define an initial color. White nor black or any gray-scale is technically an actual color - you can't saturate or rotate it. You'll have to "colorize" it somehow, and the sepia filter is the only filter which do some form of colorizing.

It would be easier if your image was pure 100% red. Then you could just add the target degree directly and adjust saturation and lightness using HSL for target. For a white color start point the first step is to convert and define an intermediate color so we can saturate and rotate it later on.

Lets first darken the white image and apply sepia to get a "base" color we can work with:

```css
filter: brightness(50%) sepia(1);
```

This will produce RGB color value of approximately:

```
rgb(178, 160, 128)
```

Step two is to [convert that to HSL color-space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2348659/1693593) which gives us:

```
hsl(38, 24.5%, 60%);
```

## Base color result

```css
div {
  background:url(http://richard.parnaby-king.co.uk/basket.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size:5em;
  width:5em;
  height:5em;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(50%) sepia(1);
  filter: brightness(50%) sepia(1);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

## Converting base color to target color

These two first steps are static and its result will be reused every time we need to find a target adjustment (the actual value of *sepia* is defined in the [SVG Filters specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#sepiaEquivalent)).

Now we need to calculate what we need to apply to this base color to get target color. First convert target color, for example #689d94 as given in the question, to HSL:

```
hsl(170, 21.3%, 51.2%);
```

Then we have to calculate the difference between those. Hue is calculated by simply subtracting base from target. The same for Saturation and Lightness, but as we assume 100% of the base value we need to subtract the result from 100% to end up with a diff for the accumulated values:

```
H:  170 - 38             ->  132°
S:  100 + (24.5 - 21.3)  ->  103.2%  (relative to base 100% =  3.2%)
L:  100 + (51.2 - 60.0)  ->   91.2%  (relative to base 100% = -8.8%)
```

Convert those values to a filter-string by appending it to the existing filter, then set it on the div:

```css
/*      ------ base color ------  -------  new target -------------------------------*/
filter: brightness(50%) sepia(1)  hue-rotate(132deg) saturate(103.2%) brightness(91.2%);
```

And to set it you would probably do something like this assuming filter and divElement are already declared:

```js
...
filter = "brightness(0.5) sepia(1) hue-rotate(132deg) saturate(103.2%) brightness(91.2%)";
divElement.style.filter = filter;
divElement.style.webkitFilter = filter;
```

Note that there is likely rounding errors as RGB is represented as integer, while HSL is floating point, so the actual result may not be exact, but it should get pretty close.

## Live example

```css
div {
  background:url(http://richard.parnaby-king.co.uk/basket.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size:5em;
  width:5em;
  height:5em;
  -webkit-filter: 
      brightness(50%) sepia(1) hue-rotate(132deg) saturate(103.2%) brightness(91.2%);
  filter: 
      brightness(50%) sepia(1) hue-rotate(132deg) saturate(103.2%) brightness(91.2%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<span style="font:14px sans-serif;padding:7px;color:#fff;background:#689d94">
Target color</span>
```

Viable alternative options are:

- Predefine SVGs with the color already set.
- Work with HSL/RGB directly in JavaScript and modify the SVG tree with the color directly for the shape rather than using filters. Filters are expensive performance wise, especially if many are chained as here and they are in addition a dominant part of a page. They are neither supported in all browsers.

Comment: This is a nice attempt but  totally misleading.

Comment: **This answer is wrong**. There is a [precise and elegant solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037023/#72369382) for this.

Comment: re: "It would be easier if your image was pure 100% red" it can be! `brightness(0) invert(30%) sepia(100%) saturate(10000%)` will get you to `#ff0000`.

Answer (score 35):

The accepted answer is wrong. Hue-rotate does not conserve saturation or brightness and you have to do crazy math to come up with the correct

[Update: OP changed their original answer to a new solution, so the observations above are no longer true]

values. The far easier way - which will result in a correct result - is to do a CSS filter that references an SVG filter. The feColorMatrix primitive in SVG filters allows you to pick a color directly.

Take your color #424242 - divide each RGB channel value by #FF and put them in the fifth column, first three rows of your color matrix. In this case, hex #42 is 68 in decimal, so divide that by 255 (#FF in decimal) and you'll get 0.257 - which you put in the fifth column, first three rows.

```css
div {
  background:url(http://richard.parnaby-king.co.uk/basket.svg) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  background-size:5em;
  width:5em;
  height:5em;
  -webkit-filter: url(#colorize);
  filter: url(#colorize);
}
```

```html
<div>
  </div>

<svg>
<defs>
<filter id="colorize" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 .257
                                 0 0 0 0 .257
                                 0 0 0 0 .257
                                 0 0 0 1 0"/>
 
/filter>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5):

## Hex Color To CSS Filter Converter

Use this website to calculate the filter:
**https://isotropic.co/tool/hex-color-to-css-filter/**

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension method in C# to do this (thanks Ωmega for the knowledge):

```
public static class ColorExtensions
{
    public static string ToSvgFilter(this string value)
    {
        Color color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(value);
        int r = Convert.ToInt16(color.R);
        int g = Convert.ToInt16(color.G);
        int b = Convert.ToInt16(color.B);

        decimal converted_r = (decimal)r / 255;
        decimal converted_g = (decimal)g / 255;
        decimal converted_b = (decimal)b / 255;

        return $"url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\"><defs><filter id=\"{value.Replace("#", "")}\" color-interpolation-filters=\"sRGB\"><feColorMatrix type=\"matrix\" values=\"0 0 0 0 {converted_r} 0 0 0 0 {converted_g} 0 0 0 0 {converted_b} 0 0 0 1 0\"/></filter></defs></svg>{value}')";
    }
}
```

Here is the usage:

```
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _menuItemSvgFilter = "#f20c96".ToSvgFilter();            

        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
```

Here is the razor:

```
<NavLink class="menu-font" href="inboundorders">
     <img src="/img/svg_icon/ICON_ORDER.svg" /> Orders
</NavLink>
```

and I added just this CSS to the razor at the bottom:

```
<style type="text/css">
.menu-font img 
{
    filter: @_menuItemSvgFilter;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

If svg are being used then ...

You can open svg files with some text editor copy and paste to html file then change path color as required.

In below example code... I just changed the path color of center ring. 
Hope this helps..

```js
        var imgg =document.getElementById("path");
        imgg.style="fill:#424242";
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg id="imgg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 296.838 296.838" style="enable-background:new 0 0 296.838 296.838;" xml:space="preserve" width="512px" height="512px">
<g>
 <path  d="M58.733,64.566L41.763,47.596C14.832,74.526,0,110.333,0,148.419s14.832,73.893,41.763,100.823l16.971-16.971   C36.335,209.874,24,180.095,24,148.419S36.335,86.964,58.733,64.566z" fill="#91DC5A"/>
 <path d="M82.137,81.969c-17.75,17.748-27.525,41.348-27.525,66.45s9.775,48.702,27.525,66.45l16.971-16.971   c-13.218-13.216-20.496-30.788-20.496-49.479s7.278-36.264,20.496-49.48L82.137,81.969z" fill="#91DC5A"/>
 <path d="M255.075,47.596l-16.971,16.971c22.399,22.397,34.733,52.177,34.733,83.853s-12.335,61.455-34.733,83.852l16.971,16.971   c26.931-26.931,41.763-62.737,41.763-100.823S282.006,74.526,255.075,47.596z" fill="#91DC5A"/>
 <path d="M214.701,81.969L197.73,98.939c13.218,13.216,20.496,30.788,20.496,49.48s-7.278,36.264-20.496,49.479l16.971,16.971   c17.75-17.748,27.525-41.348,27.525-66.45S232.451,99.717,214.701,81.969z" fill="#91DC5A"/>
 <path id="path" d="M148.586,114.789c-8.607,0-17.212,3.284-23.78,9.851c-13.131,13.133-13.131,34.424,0,47.559   c6.568,6.566,15.174,9.851,23.78,9.851c8.606,0,17.212-3.284,23.779-9.851c13.131-13.135,13.131-34.426,0-47.559   C165.798,118.073,157.192,114.789,148.586,114.789z M155.395,155.228c-2.454,2.454-5.319,2.821-6.809,2.821   c-1.489,0-4.356-0.367-6.808-2.818c-3.755-3.756-3.755-9.867-0.003-13.619c2.455-2.455,5.321-2.822,6.811-2.822   c1.489,0,4.354,0.367,6.808,2.82C159.147,145.363,159.147,151.475,155.395,155.228z" fill="#91DC5A"/>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

For background image

```js
        var myimg='url(\'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 296.838 296.838" style="enable-background:new 0 0 296.838 296.838;" xml:space="preserve" width="512px" height="512px"><g><path  d="M58.733,64.566L41.763,47.596C14.832,74.526,0,110.333,0,148.419s14.832,73.893,41.763,100.823l16.971-16.971   C36.335,209.874,24,180.095,24,148.419S36.335,86.964,58.733,64.566z" fill="#91DC5A"/><path d="M82.137,81.969c-17.75,17.748-27.525,41.348-27.525,66.45s9.775,48.702,27.525,66.45l16.971-16.971   c-13.218-13.216-20.496-30.788-20.496-49.479s7.278-36.264,20.496-49.48L82.137,81.969z" fill="#91DC5A"/><path d="M255.075,47.596l-16.971,16.971c22.399,22.397,34.733,52.177,34.733,83.853s-12.335,61.455-34.733,83.852l16.971,16.971   c26.931-26.931,41.763-62.737,41.763-100.823S282.006,74.526,255.075,47.596z" fill="#91DC5A"/><path d="M214.701,81.969L197.73,98.939c13.218,13.216,20.496,30.788,20.496,49.48s-7.278,36.264-20.496,49.479l16.971,16.971   c17.75-17.748,27.525-41.348,27.525-66.45S232.451,99.717,214.701,81.969z" fill="#91DC5A"/><path d="M148.586,114.789c-8.607,0-17.212,3.284-23.78,9.851c-13.131,13.133-13.131,34.424,0,47.559   c6.568,6.566,15.174,9.851,23.78,9.851c8.606,0,17.212-3.284,23.779-9.851c13.131-13.135,13.131-34.426,0-47.559   C165.798,118.073,157.192,114.789,148.586,114.789z M155.395,155.228c-2.454,2.454-5.319,2.821-6.809,2.821   c-1.489,0-4.356-0.367-6.808-2.818c-3.755-3.756-3.755-9.867-0.003-13.619c2.455-2.455,5.321-2.822,6.811-2.822   c1.489,0,4.354,0.367,6.808,2.82C159.147,145.363,159.147,151.475,155.395,155.228z" fill="#91DC5A"/></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g></svg> \')';
        
        document.getElementById("mydiv").style.backgroundImage =myimg ;  
        
        
        
        //changing color according to theme .. new theme color :#424242
        myimg=myimg.replace(/#91DC5A/g,"#424242");
       document.getElementById("mydiv").style.backgroundImage =myimg ;
```

```css
             div {

  background-size:5em;
  width:5em;
  height:5em;
  
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

    
    <div id="mydiv"></div>
<span style="font:14px sans-serif;padding:7px;color:#fff;background:#689d94">
Target color</span>
   
  
    
</body>
</html>
```