# Trying to understand the css filter hue-rotate thing

Tags: css, filter

I came across this tool that will be practical using the first top box (deg)

http://www.workwithcolor.com/hsl-color-picker-01.htm

I have this css code:

```
#FullMenuContent input:checked { -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(290deg); 
filter: hue-rotate(290deg);
```

That produces a color, fine. I understood that the image must have a color (does not work on grey scale). I understood that the final result depends on the color of the image, so my question is:

What should be the color of the image for the color picker linked above to be accurate?

Comment: Possible Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037023/how-to-calculate-required-hue-rotate-to-generate-specific-colour

Comment: You are right Pauie_D, I think this is my answer : "It would be easier if your image was pure 100% red. Then you could just add the target degree directly and adjust saturation and lightness using HSL for target. For a white color start point the first step is to convert and define an intermediate color so we can saturate and rotate it later on."

Comment: Also, I saw somewhere in this answer that it does not work on background images, in my case, it does. My checkboxes are styled via background images.

Comment: No, you can't apply a filter to a CSS property. You can only apply it to an **element**. The filter affects your **checkbox** which has a background image...it's not *quite* the same thing.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Thanks for the clarification.