# Change png image background color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just want to change png image background to **blue when hover** without using other image. Just only css. I've that css filters do the job so I tried few methods but no luck. I used css filter greayscale methord. Is there any to change background color to this #05adef other than greyscale? Here is the [fillde](https://jsfiddle.net/mgry0Lwh/)

```css
img{
  width: 120px;
}

img:hover{
   filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/fox-news-logo-png-transparent.png" alt="">
```

Comment: does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037023/how-to-calculate-required-hue-rotate-to-generate-specific-colour) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `background-color:#05adef`

alternatively you can `use hue-rotate(deg)`
but the catch is that you have to search for the perfect angle to match the desired color. Also use invert and contrast in conjunction for more control over the color.

```css
img{
  width: 120px;
}

img:hover{
filter:invert(100%) hue-rotate(24deg);
 
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/fox-news-logo-png-transparent.png" alt="">
```

Comment: Not this way. and not as an overlay. I need to change image colors. IS that possible?

Comment: This is great! Can't we change the black color background to blue?