# Change background image when hover not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to change background image on normal image hover. (Please don't suggest me to put this into normal background image)

I tried this way using z-index values but it's not working. Here is the [fillde](https://jsfiddle.net/58qwxat0/) It needs to preload image so user don't see image loading at all.

```css
img{
  width: 120px;
  position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

img:hover{
     background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/bsQL6SK/media13-3-blue.png');
      background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/fox-news-logo-png-transparent.png" alt="">
```

Comment: I'm curious what makes you think a background image will show through a image? It doesn't matter what you make the z-index. It's a ... wait for it ... background image. By definition it's behind the content, which happens to be an ... image. That's what "background" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a pure css solution you would have to wrap your image in a div and have the background image on the before/after element. Something like this. I added a background color just to make it more clear what is happening. The solution also depends on what you really want, to me it's a bit unclear.

```css
.container {
  width: 120px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/Rzxom/s3/lamborghini-sian-lead.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container:hover:after {
  display: block;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/fox-news-logo-png-transparent.png" alt="">
</div>
```

**EDIT**

[image]
As you can see the fox news logo is that small but your image is larger, I added the green background to make it more clear (was transparent before). What you need to do is to edit so the logo is full size. Does it make sense?

Comment: This is great! But background image is in wrong size?

Comment: let me check @Janath

Comment: @Janath the code above is correct, your image is like two images, one with transparent background and one with the image in the center smaller. So if you change that it will work as expected. The same goes for your first image, the logo itself if not 120px. I changed the image to showcase it.

Comment: Understood. Can't we hide the first image?

Comment: @Janath no, let me show you. You need to edit your images.

Comment: Actually you were correct! Made those two images same height and width. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

I checked both images and it appears that you need a bluescale image on hover. IF that's the case, you can use filter:

```
img {
  width: 120px;
}

img:hover {
  filter: sepia(100%) hue-rotate(190deg) saturate(500%);
}
```

Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/x2ywL6he/5/

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter

Comment: Blue means, I have a color code. So I need to use that one.

Comment: @Janath You can play around with the hue-rotate, saturate values to match the blue you need.

Comment: Yes my mistake! I need exactly same color. #05adef

Comment: @Janath here's a guide to convert the color: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037023/how-to-calculate-required-hue-rotate-to-generate-specific-colour

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery hover event and change the image URL and change your z-index to 0 till user can hover it

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>title</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/fox-news-logo-png-transparent.png" alt="">
</body>
<style>
img{
  width: 120px;
  position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

img:hover{
     background-image: img[back];
      background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-size: cover;
}
</style>
<script>
$('img').hover(function (e) {
 if(e.type == 'mouseenter'){
  $(this).attr('src', 'https://i.ibb.co/bsQL6SK/media13-3-blue.png');
    }else{
        $(this).attr('src', 'https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/fox-news-logo-png-transparent.png');
    }
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<img src="https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/fox-news-logo-png-transparent.png" onmouseover="this.src='https://i.ibb.co/bsQL6SK/media13-3-blue.png'" onmouseout="this.src='https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/fox-news-logo-png-transparent.png'" alt="">
```

css

```
img{
  width: 120px;
}
```

[working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5pn8h3q2/12/)

let me know if you still face issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using [onmouseover](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp) and [onmouseout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseout.asp).

```css
img{
  width: 120px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<img src='https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/fox-news-logo-png-transparent.png' onmouseover="this.src='https://i.ibb.co/bsQL6SK/media13-3-blue.png';" onmouseout="this.src='https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/fox-news-logo-png-transparent.png';" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two image tags, hide one by default and toggle display of these on hover. Something like this?

```js
const c = document.querySelector("#container");
const img1 = document.querySelector("#container .off-hover");
const img2 = document.querySelector("#container .on-hover");

c.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
  img1.style.display = "none";
  img2.style.display = "inline-block";
})

c.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
  img1.style.display = "inline-block";
  img2.style.display = "none";
})
```

```css
img{
  width: 120px;
  position: relative;
}

.on-hover {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="off-hover" alt="">
  <img src="https://cdn2.downdetector.com/static/uploads/logo/Google-new_19.png" class="on-hover">
</div>
```

Comment: Can't do that way bcz im using wordpress

Answer (score 0):

I slightly do not get what you meant by (Please don't suggest me to put this into normal background image), pardon me if I misunderstood and do the exact thing you wanted to ignore.

Without using JavaScript and just with plain CSS I can see two approaches( I am a beginner)

1. Using both the image as background images in CSS and showing/hiding accordingly, but this is not what you wanted.
2. Using both the images in HTML with img tag, you can wrap it with  tag or even a div.

But make sure both the image have same dimension

```css
img{
  width: 200px;
  
}


a img:last-child {
  width: 200px;
  display: none;  
}
a:hover img:last-child {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;  
}
a:hover img:first-child {
  width: 200px;
  display: none;  
}
```

```html
<a>
  <img  src="https://cdn.freebiesupply.com/logos/large/2x/fox-news-logo-png-transparent.png" alt="">
  <img  src="https://i.ibb.co/bsQL6SK/media13-3-blue.png" alt="">
  
</a>
```