# CSS "filter" property does not work on Safari when using inline SVG in CSS like 'filter: url(data:image, ...)'

Tags: css, svg, safari, svg-filters, css-filters

*[EDIT] I've reviewed my entire post to add precisions about the problem and for additional ressources.*
...

I'm new to SVG usage for webdesign, but I intend to implement a cool CSS feature for a theme. For information, I work with SASS to compile my styles.

**What I want to achieve is to obtain a configurable theme that can change of color simply by changing some vars in my SASS files.**

To do so :

- I use "uncolored" SVGs as background for some elements of my website.
- Then I apply a SVG filter for those elements to "colorize" them.

At this point, I'm pretty happy, because it is working... on almost all browsers : Brave, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Edge

**But it doesn't work on Safari** and I'm not sure Why :

1. it seems that I cannot use the CSS `filter` with value `url('data:image/svg+xml, <svg>...</svg>')`
2. However it seems that I can use the filter property with url value if I'm targeting an element already in the DOM.

I've found an interesting article that talk about the same problem :
https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/svgs-filters-can-be-inlined-in-css/#til%3A-svg-filters-can-be-inlined-in-css

> *I tested the included examples in Firefox 84 and and Chrome 87. It worked in Safari 14 but stopped for unknown reason.*

The "included example" being inline SVG in the CSS

Do someone know if using inline CSS SVG is possible with Safari ?

Here is an example to illustrate the problem:

```css
/* Basic style for parent */
.parent {
  border: 3px dotted violet;
  background: pink;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

/* Basic style for children */
.children {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.children::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* Using a pseudo element inside childrens that carry the background image */
.v0 .children::after, .v1 .children::after{
  background-image: url('https://public.xspawn.fr/svg-bg-btn.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

/*Creating a new stack context to be able to display text*/
.parent{position: relative; z-index:0;}
.children::after{ z-index:-1;}

/* Applying a filter to each children 'after' pseudo element to colorize its content (the SVG background or the background color) */
.children.recolor::after{
  filter : url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8, <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><filter id="recolor" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"><feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 .13725 0 0 0 0 .23137 0 0 0 0 .32157 0 0 0 1 0"/></filter></svg>#recolor');
  );
}

.children.recolor2::after{
  filter : url('#dom-filter');
}
```

```html
[v0] Element without Without SVG filter
<div class="parent v0">
  <div class="children">No filter</div>
</div>

<strong style='color:orangered;'>[v1] KO : Filtered with "filter: url(data:image... )"</strong>
<div class="parent v1">
  <div class="children recolor">filter: url(data:image..., < svg > .. .< svg \> )</div>
</div>

<strong style='color:green;'>[v2] OK : Filtered with filter DOM SVG and "filter: url('#elementid')"</strong>
<div class="parent v1">
  <div class="children recolor2">filter: url('#dom-filter')</div>
</div>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><filter id="dom-filter" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"><feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 .13725 0 0 0 0 .23137 0 0 0 0 .32157 0 0 0 1 0"/></filter></svg>
```

Comment: perhaps you should check whether this is a known [webkit issue](https://bugs.webkit.org/) and report it if not.

Comment: You were right. Known webkit issue : https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=104169

Answer (score -1):

Question: "Do someone know if using inline CSS SVG is possible with Safari ?"
Answer: "Yes it is possible".

If you use filters on svg elements in css/scss file like this

> filter: url(#filter_id);

Transfer the styles from the css/scss file into the  svg file separately into styles, and everything will work, like this:

```
<svg>
...
<g filter="url(#filter)">
..
</g>

<filter id="filter" x="5.54736" y="0" width={width-11.3} height="80.0002" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood floodOpacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10" result="effect1_foregroundBlur_326_868"/>
</filter>
</svg>
```