# How do I find the hue (or HSL)/RGB value from an input type text using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, rgb, hsl

Backstory: I made a website where you add routines in a timetable style. You select the time amount etc but also the **colour of the routine block** in the timetable. I've looked online on ways to gather RGB values but I was only able to find it after it was assigned to the div with `window.getComputedStyle`.

I want to get the hue because I want to automatically add the saturation and luminance amount to other elements of the routine div. **I don't mind getting the RGB values** if it's easier in a way because I'd like to make myself think about the conversion, I saw online that it is possible to convert from RGB to HSL.

---

So the input type text basically takes anything like "red" "green" and assigns it to the routine div, then `getComputedStyle` gives me the RGB value of it. But there's one thing that I don't like about `getComputedStyle`. It only works after the routine is added. So, I have to add the line `getComputedStyle`, after the routine div is being added. I want it to find the value from the input not, the `background-color` style like in these lines:

```
const bgCol = window.getComputedStyle(routine_element, null).getPropertyValue("background-color");
console.log("Print " + bgCol)
```

Because from what I believe, `getPropertyValue` just takes the value like "red" from the background-color, and then `getComputedStyle` turns it into RGB values. But I tried a few combinations to use just the input type text and wasn't able to get anything back.

I have a `list_element.insertBefore(routine_element, routine_f_close);` right before the `getComputedStyle` line, and it turns out the RGB values, but if I do it before, it won't work obviously, and the input variations didn't work either. Let me know if I should provide more info?

Comment: So you have an input where the user types a color (presumably an HTML color code) like "red", and from that you want to compute the corresponding saturation and luminance values?

Comment: Yes! I'm not sure if I'm replying but yeah.

Comment: You'll probably have to go with the method you're currently using (getting the RGB values of `getComputedStyle()`) for the simple reason that it's the only way I can think of to convert an HTML color code to any kind of numeric color values. From there you can [convert RGB to HSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348597/why-doesnt-this-javascript-rgb-to-hsl-code-work/54071699#54071699).